# Axon Aggregate Not Found When Trying to Update An Existing Record

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, axon

I am using Axon and MongoDB to implement a microservice using CQRS and Event Sourcing patterns. When I first start the application, everything works fine. I can create an order and update that order. After I restart the application I can still create an order and update THAT order but when I try to update previous orders, Axon throws `"Command 'com.example.demo.command.command.UpdateOrderCommand' resulted in org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateNotFoundException(The aggregate was not found in the event store)"`. My theory is that when I create an order it creates an instance of OrderAggregate and uses that instance to update. But when I restart the application that instance goes away and when updating I am not creating an OrderAggregate instance. Here is my OrderAggregate.java file:

```
package com.example.demo.command.aggreagate;

import com.example.demo.command.command.CreateOrderCommand;
import com.example.demo.command.command.UpdateOrderCommand;
import com.example.demo.common.event.OrderCreatedEvent;
import com.example.demo.common.event.OrderUpdatedEvent;
import com.example.demo.query.entity.Address;
import com.example.demo.query.entity.Product;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandHandler;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingHandler;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateIdentifier;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateLifecycle;
import org.axonframework.spring.stereotype.Aggregate;

@Aggregate
@Slf4j
public class OrderAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String _id;
    private String customerId;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private String status;
    private Product product;
    private Address address;
    private String createdAt;
    private String updatedAt;

    public OrderAggregate() {
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public OrderAggregate(CreateOrderCommand command) {
        log.info("CreateOrderCommand received.");

        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new OrderCreatedEvent(command.getId(), command.getCustomerId(),
                command.getQuantity(), command.getPrice(), "ORDERED",
                command.getProduct(), command.getAddress(), command.getCreatedAt(), command.getUpdatedAt()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(OrderCreatedEvent event) {
        log.info("An OrderCreatedEvent occurred.");
        this._id = event.getId();
        this.customerId = event.getCustomerId();
        this.quantity = event.getQuantity();
        this.price = event.getPrice();
        this.status = "CREATED";
        this.product = event.getProduct();
        this.address = event.getAddress();
        this.createdAt = event.getCreatedAt();
        this.updatedAt = event.getUpdatedAt();
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void on(UpdateOrderCommand command) {
        log.info("UpdateOrderCommand received.");

        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new OrderUpdatedEvent(command.getId(), command.getQuantity(), command.getPrice(),
                "UPDATED", command.getProduct(), command.getAddress(), updatedAt));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(OrderUpdatedEvent event) {
        log.info("An OrderUpdatedEvent occurred.");

        this.quantity = event.getQuantity();
        this.price = event.getPrice();
        this.status = event.getStatus();
        this.product = event.getProduct();
        this.address = event.getAddress();
        this.updatedAt = event.getUpdatedAt();
    }


}
```

I tried making `on(UpdateOrderCommand)` an OrderAggregate constructor. It kind of works but deletes updatedAt field when updating to database. Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
These are my AxonConfig.java and MongoConfig.java files:
AxonConfig.java

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EmbeddedEventStore;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStorageEngine;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStore;
import org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.DefaultMongoTemplate;
import org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.MongoTemplate;
import org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.eventsourcing.eventstore.MongoEventStorageEngine;
import org.axonframework.spring.config.AxonConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ValidatingMongoEventListener;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

public class AxonConfig {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedEventStore eventStore(EventStorageEngine storageEngine, AxonConfiguration configuration) {
        return EmbeddedEventStore.builder()
                .storageEngine(storageEngine)
                .messageMonitor(configuration.messageMonitor(EventStore.class, "eventStore"))
                .build();
    }

    // The `MongoEventStorageEngine` stores each event in a separate MongoDB document
    @Bean
    public EventStorageEngine storageEngine(MongoClient client) {
        return MongoEventStorageEngine.builder().mongoTemplate(DefaultMongoTemplate.builder().mongoDatabase(client).build()).build();
    }
}
```

MongoConfig.java:

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ValidatingMongoEventListener;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {
    @Bean
    ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator) {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator);
    }
}
```

Edit #2:
I updated AxonConfig.java file and this solved my problem:

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import org.axonframework.config.Configurer;
import org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer;
import org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.TokenStore;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventCountSnapshotTriggerDefinition;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.SnapshotTriggerDefinition;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStorageEngine;
import org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.DefaultMongoTemplate;
import org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.eventsourcing.eventstore.MongoEventStorageEngine;
import org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.eventsourcing.tokenstore.MongoTokenStore;
import org.axonframework.serialization.Serializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AxonConfig {
    @Autowired
    public void configuration(Configurer configurer, MongoClient client) {
        configurer.configureEmbeddedEventStore(configuration -> storageEngine(client)).eventProcessing(conf -> {
            conf.registerTokenStore(configuration -> tokenStore(client, configuration.serializer()));
        });
    }

    @Bean
    public EventStorageEngine storageEngine(MongoClient client) {
        return MongoEventStorageEngine.builder().mongoTemplate(DefaultMongoTemplate.builder().mongoDatabase(client).build()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(MongoClient client, Serializer serializer) {
        return MongoTokenStore.builder().mongoTemplate(DefaultMongoTemplate.builder().mongoDatabase(client).build()).serializer(serializer).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SnapshotTriggerDefinition snapshotTriggerDefinition(org.axonframework.config.Configuration configuration) {
        return new EventCountSnapshotTriggerDefinition(configuration.snapshotter(), 5);
    }

    @Bean
    public Configurer configurer() {
        return DefaultConfigurer.defaultConfiguration();
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, it looks like some missconfiguration on the Event Store side of your project. When you say you are using Mongo, is it for Event Store or for query/projection side? Can you share your configs (`@Bean`s created by you for example)?

Comment: My thought as well ... sounds like you are using an in memory event store so you cannot use persisted events after restart.

Comment: I used axon-mongo configuration as was described in this link: [link] (https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/mongo). I'm also going to add my AxonConfig.java file.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments on the original post, it was a configuration issue. So I went ahead and dig a little more and found github repository which had an example: (https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-mongo/tree/master/mongo-axon-example). I implemented the configuration file as was implemented in the repository above and it worked like a charm. Thanks to Lucas Campos and Jan Gelinski for pointing me in the right direction. I will edit the original post accordingly with my solution.